# Javascript/HTML passing image from HTML <td> to another <td>

Tags: javascript

I need to pass image from one cell to another. So here is mine work till now:

```
function onInit(){
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML="<td id='list1'><img src='1.jpg' width=100 height=100 onclick='click(this)'>
}
```

Here is `click` function:

```
function click(img){
  var img = img.src;
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML="<img src='img'>";
}
```

What should I do here to show image (not img), or what is right syntax for this?

Comment: document.getElementById("image").innerHTML="<img src='"+img+"'>"; should work... Of course, you could attempt to really remove the image node and then append it to the destination cell. That would be sexier.

Comment: Thanks, its working now :)
I forget that + to concatenate

Comment: Please, mark as answered. Any of the dudes below solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate:

```
.innerHTML = "<img src='"+img+"' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.src`

```
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML="<img src='"+img.src+"'>";
```

Comment: img.src would be undefined if he defines img as the img.src :) (nevermind, see you corrected it).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function click(img){
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML="<img src='"+img.src+"'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one row, i.e. there is only one `<td>` for `list` which I assume is a table.
The `<td>` isn't closed and passing `this` on click will not pass the current object reference. On click of the image, call a function which will set the innerHTML of the current `<td>` to the destined `<td>`.

```
"<td id='list1'><img src='1.jpg' width=100 height=100 onclick='click(list1)'></td>"
```

**Javascript:**

```
function click(str){
   document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML=document.getElementById(str).innerHTML;
}
```

You might want to change the click handler of the image in the destination `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by the following code:

```
function click(img) {
    var img = img.src;
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img + "'>";
}
```